# Should i try to replace an api by minimalist website

Tags: javascript, php, hapi.js

I'm working on a chrome extension and I need to get a schedule data from outside of the extension to let the admin broadcast the schedule to the extension users. I wanted to use hapi.js but I can't afford to buy any private server. I did find free website hosting. I thought I would do a minimal website with just a login system and some pages containing the data I would want and make some get request on the extension and extract the schedule on the extension. 
Is it okay like a replacement plane for the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For almost the same purpose I was using WordPress website with json api plugin. (https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) It is super easy to install and later you can simply run fetch requests inside of your application or extension.

Comment: Oh yeah right i totally forgot about wordpress. thanks man i don't need anything more than what you said just wordpress and some json perfect.